# How can i store an Integer Array in SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I have an Array called `Upval`that has 16 Integer values that I would like to store in my SharedPreferences without creating individual ones for each, but SharedPrefernces won't allow Array's, what is the simplest way of doing this?  The declaration looks something like this:

```
Integer[] UpVal = new Integer[16];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store it as a String by transforming it:

```
Arrays.toString(upVal)
```

To get it back and convert a String to an Integer array is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize an array to String using TextUtils.join(";", myInts) and the deserialize it back using something like TextUtils. SimpleStringSplitter or implement your own TextUtils.StringSplitter.